# retrieve and display individual reviews and ratings for product

Tags: product, review, ratings

I"m trying to retrieve all reviews and ratings for a product.  I'm not entirely sure how this could be accomplished.  anyone care to help a brutha out?

I am currently trying to use:

```
            $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                ->addStatusFilter(1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', $productId)
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->getItems();

            $reviewData = array();
            if (count($reviews) > 0) {
                foreach ($reviews as $r) {
                    foreach ($r->getRatingVotes() as $vote) {
                        $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
                    }
```

However, ratings[] is null when i dump the variables.

Comment: your traced down that $reviews and $vote are not empty/null?

Comment: @StefanGregori I just checked those variables and noticed that getPercent() did not have parentheses in my production environment (I copied the above from a text editor).  It appears the bug was found to be in my very own visual processing Virtual Machine :D  Your comment was that which brought this bug to my attention though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you can also get this data for all products as a collection:

```
class Amasty_Review_Model_Mysql4_Collection extends  Mage_Review_Model_Mysql4_Review_Product_Collection
{
// approved reviews plus visible in catalog products plus url revrites data
public function addVisiblityFilter()
{
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();

    $this->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
        ->addStoreFilter($store->getId()) 
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','visibility'), 'inner');

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this);   

    $urCondions = array(
        'e.entity_id=ur.product_id',
        'ur.category_id IS NULL',
        'ur.store_id='.intVal($store->getId()),
        'ur.is_system=1'
    );

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('ur' => $this->getTable('core/url_rewrite')),
        join(' AND ', $urCondions),
        array('url' => 'request_path')
    );        

    return $this;
}

public function addRatingData()
{
    $ratingTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('rating/rating_option_vote');
    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array('rat' => $ratingTable),
            'rat.review_id = rt.review_id',
            array('av_rating' => new Zend_Db_Expr('AVG(rat.percent)')))
        ->group('rt.review_id');

    return $this;        
}

}
```